# Understanding trigonometric Identities $\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

I was doing some revision and I bumped into this question.
$\cos(x) - \sec(x) = 0$, $0^\circ \le x \le 360^\circ $

I know it turns into
$\cos^2(x) - 1 = 0$  (ans: $90^\circ$, $270^\circ$)

It also equals to
$\sin^2(x) = 0$

The answer scheme gave (ans: $0^\circ$, $180^\circ$, $360^\circ$)
Why are $90^\circ$, $270^\circ$ unacceptable?
Am I missing something or is the answer scheme wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you can answer your own question.  You correctly changed the original equation from $\cos(x)-\sec(x)=0$ into $\sin^2(x)=0$.  Now... what is $\sin(90^\circ)$?  What is $\sin^2(90^\circ)$?  Is that equal to zero?  Does it satisfy the equation then?  (Note further that $\sec(90^\circ)$ is undefined)

Comment: Also, you say "$\cos^2(x)-1=0$ (ans: $90^\circ,270^\circ$)" but $\cos(90^\circ)=0$ so $\cos^2(90^\circ)-1=0^2-1=-1\neq 0$  Similarly for $270^\circ$.

Comment: Okay i understand! I didn't know there was a rule where more than sec90 is undefined, Thank you :D

Comment: $\sec(90^\circ)$ is undefined because it is division by zero.  Remember that $\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ and that $\cos(90^\circ)=0$.  On the other hand, something like $\sec(91^\circ)$ is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $\cos^2(x) - 1 = 0$ does not have solutions at $x=90^\circ,270^\circ$. This is because $\cos(90^\circ)=0$ and $\cos(270^\circ)=0$. Because of the stated trigonometric identity, it follows that $x=90^\circ,270^\circ$ are not solutions of $\sin^2(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from $\frac{cos^2(x)-1}{cos(x)}=0$which implies $\frac{-sin^2(x)}{cos(x)}={tan(x)}.{sin(x)}=0$ so these are $0$ at ${0,180,360}$ . Thus the  answer is ${0,180,360}$